# Summing up values of Some rows and add it to Value of other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I need your help in SQL Query where in the example table given below, i just need two rows which doesn't have a Required flag set to **Y**. Value of these two rows should have **(Price * % Levied) + (sum of (Price)*(% Levied) of rows which has Required flag set to Y)**

| Name | Price | % Levied | Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| King Bed | 10000 | 120 |  |
| Queen Bed | 24000 | 140 |  |
| Delivery | 240 | 140 | Y |
| Porter Charges | 20 | 20 | Y |

My result should look something like this

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| King Bed | (10000 * 120)+(240 * 140)+(20 * 20) |
| Queen Bed | (24000 * 140)+(240 * 140)+(20 * 20) |

I don't even know where to get started. Let me know if any info is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.Price * t1.Levied + t3.CommonPayment Values
FROM table t1
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(t2.Price * t2.Levied) CommonPayment
             FROM table t2 
             WHERE t2.Required = 'Y' ) t3 
WHERE t1.Required <> 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
with required_rows as
(
    select  Price * '% Levied' as 'add_on_price'
    from    my_table
    where   Required = 'Y'
),
sum_required_rows as
(
    select sum (add_on_price) as total_add_on_price
    from   required_rows 
),
select  Name,
        Price,
        % Levied,
        ((Price * '% Levied') + total_add_on_price) as final_price
from    my_table
inner join sum_required_rows on 1=1
where   Required != 'Y'
```